# Find Duplicated Key in a complicated React component

Tags: reactjs, duplicates, key, components

I have a react component, which generate many keys for a time, I am not sure which one is not unique. The error is as below. Any easy way to help debugging? thanks!

react.js:19500 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `MyGrid`. See https ://fb.me/ react-warning-keys for more information.

Comment: please paste your code

Answer (score 8):

This is a warning that you have NOT assigned a key, rather than it isn't actually unique, the next line of the message should tell you exactly what is the offending element - see an example below `in div (created by CardsComponent)`

`` warning.js:36 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `CardsComponent`. See fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.
    in div (created by CardsComponent) ``

If you want to debug further the test is done in `ReactElementValidator.validateExplicitKey` which simply does a check for if the element key being non null, no checking of uniqueness amongst sibling keys...

```
function validateExplicitKey(element, parentType) {
  if (!element._store || element._store.validated || element.key != null) {
    return;
  }
  // if it gets here it has failed and you will be warned
```

The interesting part here being `element.key != null` as the others pass as virtue of already having been validated

Comment: alechill, how to use the validateExplicitKey function to debug? How to call it? Looks like you trimmed the ending of the function

Answer (score 3):

Click to expand the error in the console to reveal the stack trace. Follow the calls up to the one before `createElementWithValidation` and it should show you the culprit line number.

Log the keys you're using there. If there's a ton, put them in an array and `[].filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i)`