# ReactJS: Is there a way to see the values used for the key property required for lists

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the common error:  **Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.**

In general, finding the offending code is easy, but this time it is not.   What I would like to know is what are the key values for the items being displayed.

**(Q) Is there a way for me to see what each key property's value in the DOM that is rendered?**

When I inspect the HTML generated *lists* that react has rendered, I don't see the key property on the DOM elements (nor would I expect to see it), but that is what I'm asking to see.  **Is there a flag I can set to ask React to add that key property value to the DOM so I can see it?**

This would let me see where I'm missing a key, or have two keys with the same value (this is the problem I think I have). See [Find Duplicated Key in a complicated React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948280/find-duplicated-key-in-a-complicated-react-component)

At this point, I'm doing the methodical approach of rendering one item at a time to isolate which item has the problem so I can zero in and find the offending code.

## Searching for solutions

When searching for solutions there are several good write ups on how this works and why keys are needed, and they are shown below.

- Similar question (OKs same question as mine, but no answer) - [Cant find react error which child is missing key prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630833/cant-find-react-error-which-child-is-missing-key-prop)
- Excellent question about how keys work and a great answer.   See [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js/43892905#43892905)
- The ReactJS docs on using Keys and mis-using them.  See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys.
- An npm library that helps solve this problem.  See https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-key-index
- How do you track down duplicate keys - [Find Duplicated Key in a complicated React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948280/find-duplicated-key-in-a-complicated-react-component)

Comment: Have you tried using [React DevTool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)? It will let you see props for each components.

Comment: Are you setting a key in the first place? It sounds like you are iterating through an array and rendering a react component for each value. Take a look at the [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) section of the official docs.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Best solution is to rely on a unique value. If you're not able to provide that based on any specific property of your data structure then use index of your loop. If you can't use index as you need to move the items in the list then you can generate a unique ID from your data structure. Best would be JSON.stringify() ;)

Comment: @Min Lee, I'm not using React DevTool, and will look into that.  Does that show the key values?

Comment: @ravibagul91, Sorry I can't post the code.  I don't have the problem isolated to a small set of files.

Comment: @woat, I can't know for sure that I'm setting a key either.  I'm instrumenting the code now, with console.log() statements of the keys that I'm using to see if any are null, or not unique.

Comment: @PatS Yes, the dev tool will allow you to see the tree structure of all your components alongside with keys, props, and states. You should be able to see it if you are setting a key properly (ex: `<MyComponent key={myUniqueKey}/>`)

Comment: @PatS, the error you posted will come in 2 scenarios. First, if you don't set key at all and second if you have repeating key. Be sure for any loop you are setting unique key.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some explanation why **Key** is important and how to provide it to an array of children in React:

There are three List component in the example below. If you open it in the Chrome DevTools and click on the "Randomize sort" you will realize that the children of the lists are changing (they blink) but in the second example some more of the `li` elements are changing, the reason is React is **removing and re-creating** the `li` tag.

The efficient examples are the first and third List component because React knows instead of removing these group of elements it can to re-order them which is way faster!

I **would NOT recommend** the third (JSON.stringify) example, better always rely on a unique property from the data structure to avoid extra work.

```js
const items = Array(10).fill(null).map((_, idx) => ({ id: String(idx) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999), title: 'Item '+(idx+1) }));

function List({ children, items, keyProp, indexType }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ borderBottom: '1px solid black', padding: '1em' }}>
      <h2>{children}</h2>
      <ul>
        {items.map((data, idx) => {
          const key = indexType === 'dataStructure'
            ? data[keyProp]
            : indexType === 'jsonStringify'
              ? JSON.stringify(data)
              : idx;
          return (
            <li key={key}>{data.title}, key: {key}</li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { items };
    this.handleRandomize = this.handleRandomize.bind(this);
  }
  handleRandomize() {
    this.setState({ items: items.slice().sort(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 2) - 1) });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ background: 'red', marginBottom: '2em' }}>
        <button onClick={this.handleRandomize}>Randomize sort</button>
        <List items={this.state.items} indexType='dataStructure' keyProp='id'>
          <p>List renderd with unique "id" from data structure</p>
        </List>
        <List items={this.state.items} indexType='arrayIndex'>
          <p>List rendered with index of the loop</p>
        </List>
        <List items={this.state.items} indexType='jsonStringify'>
          <p>List rendered with JSON.stringify()</p>
        </List>
      </div> 
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```